# File Exists in WPF

Tags: c#

```
if (!File.Exists("SomeFile.exe"))
{
//Does not exists
}
```

I have SomeFile.exe in the same path as the exe but the result is Does not Exists.

This does not happen in Windows Form, does something change?

Comment: Please check a file location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this to get the file in the executables directory.

```
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, "SomeFile.exe");

if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    // 1337 code here plx.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your testing it from VS then the current directory is the Project dir not the release/debug folder (where your exe is)

Comment: Maybe you should give us some more info. Does not exist indicates a file location problem, therefore print out the current path in both applications. The current directory could be different than the folder where your exe is. Hence my answer.